# Can anyone please explain how the Spring's Multipartfile works?

Tags: java, spring-mvc

> i've been trying to understand how the multipartfile works in spring
>   but did't find out any helpful info on internet.

**Trying to understand this method:**

```
 public String copyUploadedImage(MultipartFile multipartFile, String realpath, int userId) throws IOException {
        String orgFileName = null;
        orgFileName = multipartFile.getOriginalFilename();
        String fileName = null;
        InputStream inputStream = null;
        OutputStream outputStream = null;
        if (multipartFile.getSize() > 0) {
            inputStream = multipartFile.getInputStream();
            String root = realpath + File.separator + userId + File.separator + "Image" + File.separator;
            File file = new File(root + File.separator);
            if (file.mkdirs()) {
                System.out.println("Directory is created!");
            } else {
                System.out.println("Failed to create directory!");
            }
            fileName = file + File.separator + multipartFile.getOriginalFilename();
            outputStream = new FileOutputStream(fileName);
            int readBytes = 0;
            byte[] buffer = new byte[10000];
            while ((readBytes = inputStream.read(buffer, 0, 10000)) != -1) {

                outputStream.write(buffer, 0, readBytes);
            }
            outputStream.flush();
            outputStream.close();
            inputStream.close();
        }
        return orgFileName;
    }
```

Comment: What exactly do you want to know? How MultipartFile works or what the method is doing (short answer: it saves an uploaded (image) file in a directory based on the given `realpath` and `userId` parameters)?

Comment: @quatax thanks for response. I know why it is used in applications but i just want to know how it works internally to store a file into DB.

Comment: The file isn't stored in a database in this method. It gets written to the file system.

Comment: @quatax ,ok but how it actually works internally?

Comment: So, you want to know how Java writes Bytes to the file system?

Comment: oh yes. Exactly.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/183939/discussion-between-shaik-baji-vali-and-quatax).